# make wget fail silently, without needing user input

Tags: batch-file, wget

I have a batch script that makes backups from remote camera drives on a private network using wget:

```
echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR %%i in (1 2 3 4 5) DO (
wget64 --http-user admin --http-password instar -r -l inf -nc -e robots=off --directory-prefix=C:/temp/VID_DOWNLOAD -A "*.avi" -R "*999999.avi" http://192.168.0.11%%i/sd/
)
```

Sometimes (I have not been able to identify why), the wget encounters a problem and must terminate. This generates a dialogue that requires user interaction.

It does not bother me if there is an error, since the script is launched automatically every 5 minutes and wget eventually works fine. The problem is that I manually have to intervene and acknowledge the error.

I don't have much information about the error - it shows up like this:
[image]

Would it be possible to get wget to fail silently?

Comment: Whithout knowing the error it is quite impossible to help you...

Comment: Post the error.

Comment: Try use  `-i` turns off interactive prompting during multiple file transfers.

Comment: Ok, I have added some more information. The problem only occurs on my laptop.